# Display Image on web page using Java

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets

In my `Java EE` app, there is a function to upload images. When uploading an image, I'm saving `image path` in `MySQL` database.

Now I want to display uploaded image on a web page using `image path that saved when uploading the image` in my `MySQL database table`.

How could I do this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends. Is the path someplace that a web server is serving documents from? Then just include the path, adjusted as necessary, in an `IMG` tag. If not, or if the image data itself is actually in the database (you're not entirely clear about this) then create a servlet which returns the contents of an image based on query parameters, and use that servlet's URL (plus the query parameters) in the `SRC` attribute of the `IMG` tag.

Answer (score 3):

Write a servlet that extracts your stored image from database and writes back into servlet outputstream.
You need to set the relevant mime type of the image, for example "image/jpeg", before writing into outputstream.

You need to point the image source to this servlet url with required input parameters to load the correct image from the database. For example :

```
<img src="http://mydomain/servlet/imageServlet?imgid=xyz" />
```

There is nice example given by BalusC at: [*ImageServlet serving from database*](http://balusc.blogspot.in/2007/04/imageservlet.html)